# Laravel "No query results for model [App\Schedule]" error when not calling model

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I have a perplexing issue that I cannot seem to figure out. I am trying to load a webpage from a button, but it keeps poping up the error `No query results for model [App\Schedule]`. I have no idea why it's doing that, as there is nowhere I am trying to access that model when trying to load the webpage. Below is what I have so far (it's a work in progress)

Here is the link:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" href="/schedule/availability">Set Availability</a>
```

Here is the Route:

```
Route::get('/schedule/availability', 'ScheduleController@getAvailabilityCalendar');
```

Here is the method inside of the ScheduleController:

```
 public function getAvailabilityCalendar(){
        $dt = Carbon::now('America/Los_Angeles');
        $return['DayOfWeek'] = $dt->dayOfWeek;
        $return['DisplayDays'] = (($dt->daysInMonth + $return['DayOfWeek'] + 1) <= 35) ? 34:41;



        return view('contractors.availability', compact('return'));
    }
```

And here is the view that is returned:

```
   <div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Sunday </th>
        <th>Monday </th>
        <th>Tuesday </th>
        <th>Wednesday </th>
        <th>Thursday </th>
        <th>Friday </th>
        <th>Saturday </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        @for ($i = 0, $j=-$return['DayOfWeek']; $i <= $return['DisplayDays']; $i++, $j++)

            @if($i < $return['DayOfWeek'])
                <td></td>
            @else
                @if($i %7 == 0)
    </tr><tr>
        @endif
        @if($j < 30)
            <td>{{\Carbon\Carbon::now('America/Los_Angeles')->addDays($i-$return['DayOfWeek']+1)->format('F jS')}}
                <hr>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-content="Add Times available in the following format: 10:00am-4:00pm. You may also add multiple blocks of time separated by comma. Example: 10:00am-12:00pm, 2:00pm-4:00pm">Available Time</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control availability" />
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="all-day-check" />All Day</label>
                </div>
            </td>


        @else
            <td></td>
        @endif
        @endif
        @endfor

    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>

    <script>
        $(document).on('change', '.all-day-check', function(){
            if (this.checked) {
                $(this).closest("input.availability").prop("disabled", true);

            }else{
                $(this).closest("input.availability").prop("disabled", false);
            }
        });

    </script>
```

I can't find anywhere that would need a reference to the App\Schedule model, which is a model in my project. I am at a total loss as to what it could be or why it's trying to run something I never asked it to run.

Edit: There is also no other instance of `/schedule/availability` in the routes file as well, I triple checked.

Update: Here is the Constructor for ScheduleController:

```
public function __construct()
  {
      $this->middleware('auth'); //Check is user is logged in
  }
```

Here is the stacktrace I received (For some reason, it didn't show up in my error log so I only have the screenshot)

[image]

Comment: uh, any stacktrace? that'd be helpful. also care to post the full code of `ScheduleController`? perhaps its something in the constructor..

Comment: I can post the constructor, the whole Schedule Controller is about 1,000 lines long. Also, I will add the Stacktrace as well.

Comment: ok, this is weird, i do wonder if the controller is bound to `Schedule` model somehow. and the reason i ask for the constructor is you can [type hint another class](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers) in it.. nevertheless, i do wonder if you have `Route::resource` for the same `/schedule` path just before your current route.. if it does, move your current route up.

Comment: have you fired `php artisan route:clear` once moving the `/schedule` down?

Comment: That might have been it. I placed it above the /schedule resource I had and it seems to be working now. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: glad it worked, and somehow the question become pretty much messy is it >.< happy coding nevertheless!

Comment: Yup, it happens.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out in the discussion in comments above. The culprit is narrowed down to a conflicting route.

```
 Route:something('/schedule', ...)
```

was found before

```
 Route::get('/schedule/availability', 'ScheduleController@getAvailabilityCalendar');
```

and the `Route:something` fires before the desired route. It should be noted that route defined first will be the first one to serve. This is the reason why `Route:resource` should be put after your custom `Route:get` or another routes to avoid confusion.

Next item in the list when changing routes but it does not updated, alwasy fire a `php artisan route:clear`. It will clear the route caches - can check in the docs.